# Значение символа $

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, vue.js, события, синтаксис

Что означает символ `$` в команде `this.$emit` во Vue (или этот синтаксис относится к Javascript, но все равно напишите, что он значит)? Почему нельзя написать `this.emit` вместо `this.$emit`? Во Vue я думал, что `this.$emit` - это метод, а не свойство.

Comment: Это просто часть имени переменной... Например jQuery вообще по умолчанию использует однобуквенную переменную `$`... Так же еще используют `_` как однобуквенное имя для переменной.

Comment: @ksa т. е. `$emit` - имя переменной, а я думал, что это метод. см. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vmw7quCVphw&list=PL-wEcSTifrSn5cae0gFQ7Gy7v3t6c7hLF&index=4&t=375s

Comment: Даже если метод... У метода так же будет имя и оно ничем не отличается от имен переменных. https://learn.javascript.ru/variables#variable-naming

Comment: У классов к именам свойств или методов есть еще "прибамбасы"... https://learn.javascript.ru/private-protected-properties-methods

Comment: знаком $ в vue отмечаются встроенные методы и переменные, чтобы не путать их с пользовательскими.

Answer (score 0):

В vue $ символ — соглашение, чтобы обозначить, что свойство или метод является частью экземпляра Vue. Нечто аналогичное можно сказать и про jQuery.

В данном конкретном случае $emit - это встроенный метод Vue.

Если написать просто this.emit, без знака $, то будет выдана ошибка, поскольку он будет считаться пользовательским методом, который не определен в коде.